# Return in Java Generics

Tags: java

```
public T get(int index) {           
       if(index > -1 && index < array.length)
            return array[index];
       else
            System.out.println("Invalid Index");

       return 0;    
 }
```

I am facing a problem on return value on Last Line. How and What value should i return in this scenario?

Comment: Well, that's for you to decide what the appropriate behavior is.  You could return null, return some other value from the array, or throw an exception.

Comment: You may return `null`

Comment: Does `T` have an upper bound of `Number` or `Integer`?

Comment: T is a contextual parameter, you have to show the class where it belongs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few possible options depending on which you find most appropriate.

1. return null
2. throw an exception
3. return an [`Optional<T>`](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional)

if you're going to proceed with the [`Optional<T>`](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) approach then you'll need to change the return type of your method as well as some of the logic within the method i.e.:

```
public Optional<T> get(int index) {    
       if(index > -1 && index < array.length)
           return Optional.ofNullable(array[index]);
       else
           System.out.println("Invalid Index");  

       return Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can always return `null`, but this may or may not be what you want depending on the situation.

Sometimes it is better to `throw` some exception (`NoSuchElementException` , `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ... etc)

Answer (score 0):

Make `T` a generic type which has an upper bound at most `Number`, then cast explicitly the int array elements :

```
public <T extends Number> T get(int index) {

 if (index > -1 && index < array.length)
        return (T) new Integer(array[index]);
 else
        System.out.println("Invalid Index");
 return (T) new Integer(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot return whatever you want is because the compiler doesn't know the type at this point - you have to instantiate it with a generic parameter.
When creating a generic class you have to stick to the contract - when class returns T, you have to end the method with "return objectOfTypeT" (or throw exception, as others have said).

Your case however is a perfect example of a situation, where an exception should be thrown, returning nulls may cause a lot of problems in the future.